# Verify Access Token (Facebook) and fetch user profile details

Tags: facebook

I have integrated firebase on website and able to get the information.

Now need to validate the **accessToken** on server which is fetched from web.

**1st Step**

Generating access_token by using below api

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=1234&client_secret=some_secret&grant_type=client_credentials

which gives below json

```
{
    "access_token": "1234|some_secret_here",
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

**2nd Step**

Now using the **access_token** fetched from 1st step. Need to fetch user details from facebook and also validate the **accessToken** fetched from website.

Using below api to do it.

https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=accessToken_fetched_web&access_token=1234|some_secret_here

which results in

```
{
    "data": {
        "error": {
            "code": 190,
            "message": "Bad signature"
        },
        "is_valid": false,
        "scopes": []
    }
}
```

Not sure whats the issue. Can someone help me out to validate the accessToken & fetch the user details from Facebook

Comment: You don’t need to specifically validate the token in such a situation to begin with - just fetch the user details; if that succeeds, then you _did have_ a valid token.

Comment: @CBroe you mean to say fetch the profile details directly using ->  https://graph.facebook.com/user_id?fields=id,name&access_token=token

Comment: Yes. Only you probably don’t have the user id at that point already, so use `/me` instead. (That is a shortcut, that automatically resolves to the user id or page id the token used for the request belongs to.)